How to add Arch boot entry to Ubuntu grub?
So i tried to add Arch Linux besides my already existing setup of Ubuntu and Windows. I already set up arch on another partition and ran update-grub on my ubuntu to update the menu entry to arch to the grub configuration file, but Arch's menu entry doesn't show up in the grub configuration file even after getting detected in os prober. Please help.

Edit:Output of udo sed -n '/### BEGIN.*linux/,$p' /boot/grub/grub.cfg:
Also I don't know if this is relevant in any way, but I copied the output of update-grub to another file just to see what the output was, thinking that maybe the update is happening on another file which is not the grub.cfg. Turns out update-grub even after detecting Arch of /dev/sda9 still spits out the old grub file instead of including the new grub.cfg with Arch configuration included in it.

Is Arch a standard file system like ext4? If not you may need to add drivers. Sometimes you just have to copy the boot stanza from another install into 40_custom. How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen  & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&p=13787614#post13787614

Please [edit] your question and add the output of sudo sed -n '/### BEGIN.*linux/,$p' /boot/grub/grub.cfg so we can see what is in the generated grub.cfg file after your update-grub command.

@oldfred if it were installed on a non-standard filesystem (which would be very odd) then wouldn't it also not be seen by update-grub? As it is detected there, I suspect that means the filesystem is just fine, right?

Non-standard may still be Linux standard but Ubuntu does not have that driver by default unless Ubuntu also using that configuration. Grub os-prober only works with whatever drivers are installed. I have seen users have to add drivers especially LVM tools. Sometimes users just need to mount the other file system for os-prober to see it. And Other times they have to copy boot stanza into 40_custom.

@oldfred the file system for Arch is ext4.

@tedron I added a link to the output of the filter command on my grub.cfg in the edit.

If you get grub.cfg.new, then there is a typo somewhere. I once left off a ending } in a boot stanza in 40_custom. It said error was at end of file, so took a bit to figure out issue. Can you just copy Arch boot stanza into Ubuntu's 40_custom. I prefer to turn off os-prober as I have multiple installs, some obsolete which I do not want in grub menu. So I only add those I want into 40_custom. Update is also faster as it does not have to scan entire system looking for other systems.

@oldfred I ran a find command to search for grub.cfg.new in my root, did'nt find anything as such.

@oldfred where do i get the Arch boot stanza?

Mount Arch partition and look for /boot/grub/grub.cfg or grub.conf, not sure what Arch uses. Older example here, but you have to update UUIDs and root definition. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&p=13787614#post13787614 Easier just to copy from your Arch. Only difference may be what drive you boot from whether hd0, hd1 or other. Default boot is always hd0, but if booting from another drive, then hdX can change.
